# Extrayendo una lista de una BD MySQL los valores de DATA me sale la fecha de hoy en vez de NULL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, date, null

He creado una base de datos con MySql y al extraer los datos de fechas en una lista me sale la fecha americana (y/m/d)y donde no hay valores no me sale nada.
Le he puesto un date_format para cambiar el formato y bien. En "Fecha emision" todos los campos contienen una fecha.

```
 <?php

    $consulta ="SELECT * FROM FACTURAS ORDER BY Id DESC"; 

    $resultados=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){


    ?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>        
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Num. Factura'] ?></td>     
        <td><?php 
          $date1=date_create($mostrar['Fecha Emision']); 
          echo date_format($date1,"d/m/Y");
          ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Vencimiento']);?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Base'] . "€" ?></td>        
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['IVA Soportado'] . "€"?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Total'] . "€" ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Supervisor'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Empresa'] ?></td>

      </tr>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
```

El problema lo tengo al intentar poner fecha en "Vencimiento" que no todos los registros tienen fecha. Al intentar poner otro formato (d/m/y), donde no hay datos me aparece la fecha de hoy en todos los registros donde no hay fecha.

```
<?php

    $consulta ="SELECT * FROM FACTURAS ORDER BY Id DESC"; 

    $resultados=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){


    ?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>        
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Num. Factura'] ?></td>     
        <td><?php 
          $date1=date_create($mostrar['Fecha Emision']); 
          echo date_format($date1,"d/m/Y");
          ?></td>
        <td><?php 
          $venci=date_create($mostrar['Vencimiento']);
          echo date_format($venci,"d/m/Y");
          ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Base'] . "€" ?></td>        
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['IVA Soportado'] . "€"?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Total'] . "€" ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Supervisor'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['Empresa'] ?></td>

      </tr>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar/orientar???
Gracias

Comment: if($variable_fecha !== null) { echo date_format($variable_fecha, 'd/m/Y'); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te sugiero que pongas una condicional cuando el registro no tenga datos.

```
<td><?php
    if( $mostrar['Vencimiento'] ){         
          $venci=date_create($mostrar['Vencimiento']);
          echo date_format($venci,"d/m/Y");
    }          
     ?></td>
```